# Have sed ignore non-matching lines

Tags: sed

How can I make `sed` filter matching lines according to some expression, but ignore non-matching lines, instead of letting them print?

As a real example, I want to run `scalac` (the Scala compiler) on a set of files, and read from its `-verbose` output the `.class` files created. `scalac -verbose` outputs a bunch of messages, but we're only interested in those of the form `[wrote some-class-name.class]`.
What I'm currently doing is this (`|&` is bash 4.0's way to pipe stderr to the next program):

```
$ scalac -verbose some-file.scala ... |& sed 's/^\[wrote \(.*\.class\)\]$/\1/'
```

This will extract the file names from the messages we're interested in, but will also let all other messages pass through unchanged! Of course we could do instead this:

```
$ scalac -verbose some-file.scala ... |& grep '^\[wrote .*\.class\]$' |
  sed 's/^\[wrote \(.*\.class\)\]$/\1/'
```

which works but looks very much like going around the real problem, which is how to instruct `sed` to ignore non-matching lines from the input. So how do we do that?

Comment: The accepted answer should be the one by mouviciel: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665574/869951

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Another way with plain sed:

```
sed -e 's/.../.../;t;d'
```

`s///` is a substituion, `t` without any label conditionally skips all following commands, `d` deletes line.

No need for perl or grep.

(edited after Nicholas Riley's suggestion)

Comment: On OS X 10.8.2 I had to separate `tx` and `d` with a newline rather than a semicolon as I was getting `undefined label 'x;d;:x'`.

Comment: Even better: `sed -e 's/.../.../' -e 'tx' -e 'd' -e ':x'` (suggested in a comment on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1252191/312785)).

Comment: 't' will transfer to the end of the script if no label is supplied, so simpler: `sed -e 's/.../.../' -e 't' -e 'd'`.

Comment: People dont know the meaning of `-e` option so dont mention about it generally.

Comment: undefined label 'd'

Answer (score 300):

If you don't want to print lines that don't match, you can use the combination of

- `-n` option which tells sed not to print
- `p` flag which tells sed to print what is matched

This gives:

```
sed -n 's/.../.../p'
```

Additionally, you can use a preceding matching pattern `/match only these lines/` to only apply the replacement command to lines matching this pattern.

This gives:

```
sed -n '/.../ s/.../.../p'
```

e.g.:

```
# replace all occurrences of `bar` with `baz`
sed -n 's/bar/baz/p'

# replace `bar` with `baz` only on lines matching `foo`
sed -n '/foo/ s/bar/baz/p'
```

See also [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63093517/311288) addressing [Rapsey's comment below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665549/have-sed-ignore-non-matching-lines#comment64168038_1665574) on multiple replacements

Comment: One downside to this approach is if you have multiple expressions that match, the result will also be printed multiple times. For example:  `echo foo | sed -n -e 's/foo/bar/p' -e 's/bar/oof/p'` will output both `bar` and `oof` on separate lines. Although the goto-label variety cannot handle multiple patterns either since it will delete the line if the first pattern does not match.

Comment: @Rapsey that's because you are telling it to print twice.  In the single sed command you've told it to print twice, each instance is printed in-situ (or maybe buffered).  You'd either have to pipe instead of -e or only put 'p' on the last -e.

Comment: @microbial, it won't work since the last p flag will work _on each matched line_ by the last substitution expression.

Answer (score 4):

Rapsey raised a relevant point about multiple substitutions expressions.

- First, [quoting an Unix SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/37519/138686), you can "prefix most sed commands with an address to limit the lines to which they apply".
- Second, you can group commands within curly braces **`{}`** (separated with a semi-colon **`;`** or a new line)
- Third, add the print flag **p** on the last substitution

Syntax:

```
sed -n -e '/^given_regexp/ {s/regexp1/replacement1/flags1;[...];s/regexp1/replacement1/flagsnp}'
```

---

Example (see [Here document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) for more details):

- Code:

  ```
  sed -n -e '/^ha/ {s/h/k/g;s/a/e/gp}' <<SAMPLE
  haha
  hihi
  SAMPLE
  ```
- Result:

  ```
  keke
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/.../!p'
```

There is no need for a substitution.

Comment: Or `sed '/.../ d'` for deleting lines that *do* match