# Change sed line separator to NUL to act as "xargs -0" prefilter?

Tags: sed, xargs

I'm running a command line like this:

```
filename_listing_command | xargs -0 action_command
```

Where `filename_listing_command` uses null bytes to separate the files -- this is what `xargs -0` wants to consume.

Problem is that I want to filter out some of the files. Something like this:

```
filename_listing_command | sed -e '/\.py/!d' | xargs ac
```

but I need to use `xargs -0`.

How do I change the line separator that sed wants from newline to NUL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipe it through `grep`:

```
filename_listing_command | grep -vzZ '\.py$' | filename_listing_command
```

The `-z` accepts null terminators on input and the `-Z` produces null terminators on output and the `-v` inverts the match (excludes).

**Edit:**

Try this if you prefer to use `sed`:

```
filename_listing_command | sed 's/[^\x0]*\.py\x0//g' | filename_listing_command
```

Comment: Your `sed` solution still breaks on `\n`, so if a filename contains `\n` and ends in `.py`, only the part after `\n` will be deleted. For example, `printf '%s\0' $'abc\ndef.py' | sed 's/[^\x0]*\.py\x0//g'` will print `abc\n`. This defeats the purpose of using null terminators.

Comment: In my case, my command (for `\n` terminators) was `sed -ne 's/^UU //p'`, and I couldn't convert it to a `grep` command easily.

Comment: @musiphil: Try: `grep -PzZo '^(?<=UU ).*'`

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Thanks, but it doesn't work. You can try this test case: `printf '%s\0' 'UU abc.py' | cmd` with your `grep` as `cmd`, and `abc.py\0` is expected but `grep` prints nothing (and leaves an exit status of 1).

Comment: @musiphil: Sorry, put the carat inside the lookbehind: `grep -PzZo '(?<=^UU ).*'`. Unfortunately, the `-o` causes a newline to be added. Without it, the output is null-terminated, but the "UU " isn't stripped. I think that a feature should be added so that `-z` combined with `-o` outputs nulls.

Comment: @DennisWilliamson: Thanks. It seems that `-o` combined with `-z` prevents `grep` from treating newlines as ordinary characters. I tried `printf '%s\0' $'UU abc\ndef.py' | grep -PzZo '(?<=^UU ).*'` and only `abc\n` is printed; `printf '%s\0' $'UU abc\ndef.py' | grep -PzZ '(?<=^UU ).*'` correctly prints the whole name, but as you mentioned the initial `UU ` isn't stripped. I believe this is a bug, but they say that `-P` is _highly experimental_ anyway. :-(

Comment: Pitty that `grep -zZ` options are not in POSIX, which holds also for `\x0` in `sed`. These are Gnu extensions. E.g. on Mac, you are doomed.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `git status -sz | grep -z '^UU ' | sed -rz 's/^UU (.*)/\1/' | xargs -0 $EDITOR`. Works with `sed (GNU sed) 4.2.2`

Answer (score 22):

If you've hit this SO looking for an answer and are using GNU sed 4.2.2 or later, it now has a -z option which does what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 1):

If none of your file names contain newline, then it may be easier to read a solution using GNU Parallel:

```
filename_listing_command | grep -v '\.py$' | parallel ac
```

Learn more about GNU Parallel http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OpaiGYxkSuQ

Answer (score 0):

With help of [Tom Hale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3756374/change-sed-line-separator-to-nul-to-act-as-xargs-0-prefilter#comment67494798_3756732) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665574/3195266) answer we have:

`sed -nzE "s/^$PREFIX(.*)/\1/p"`