# Sed: syntax error with unexpected "("

Tags: perl, sed, runtime-error

I've got `file.txt` which looks like this:

```
C00010018;1;17/10/2013;17:00;18;920;113;NONE
C00010019;1;18/10/2013;17:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010020;1;19/10/2013;19:00;18;920;0;NONE
```

And I'm trying to do two things:

1. Select the lines that have `$id_play` as 2nd field.
2. Replace `;` with `-` on those lines.

My attempt:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$id_play=3;
$input="./file.txt";
$result = `sed s@^\([^;]*\);$id_play;\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\);\([^;]*\)\$@\1-$id_play-\2-\3-\4-\5-\6@g $input`;
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why?

Comment: Do you have to use sed?

Comment: Seems pretty strange to run a sed one-liner from inside Perl.

Comment: the `@g` will need to be escaped as perl will process it as an array. Turn on strict with `use strict` to catch that in perl

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to escape the `@` characters, add 2 backslashes in some cases (thanks ysth!), add single quotes between sed and make it also [filter the lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665549/ignore-non-matching-lines). So replace with this:

```
$result = `sed 's\@^\\([^;]*\\);$id_play;\\([^;]*\\);\\([^;]*\\);\\([^;]*\\);\\([^;]*\\);\\([^;]*\\);\\([^;]*\\)\$\@\\1-$id_play-\\2-\\3-\\4-\\5-\\6-\\7\@g;tx;d;:x' $input`;
```

---

PS. What you are trying to do can be achieved in a much more clean way without calling `sed` and using a [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html). For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $id_play=3;
my $input="file.txt";
open (my $IN,'<',$input);
while (<$IN>) {
    my @row=split/;/;
    print join('-',@row) if $row[1]==$id_play;
}
close $IN;
```

Comment: that doesn't work for me; I think some \ need to be doubled still

Comment: If I were to use the `$` anchor in the sed expression, do I have to escape it as well?

Comment: ysth I think you are right. no error is thrown, but the regex doesn't do what is supposed to. I'll check and update

Comment: thank you that's kind :) but actually it isn't again totally correct! it replaces the `;` to `-` but doesn't filter the lines!

Comment: I was assuming it wasn't supposed to filter them, but you may very well be right

Comment: @ysth, what other characters do I need to escape? And why, exactly??

Comment: a command in backslashes uses perl's double-quotish interpolation, which allows interpolating variables (preceded by `$` or `@`) and backslash sequences (e.g. \n for a newline); so you need to escape $, @, and \.

Comment: @ysth, what about this? `$res = \`echo "$res" | grep '-66-[^-\]*-[^-]*-[^-]*\$'\`;` I'm getting an error: `grep: invalid option -- '-'`

Comment: grep interprets anything starting with - to be an option; make it `grep -e '-66...`

Comment: @ysth, ok, last question: `\`echo "$line" | sed 's/-[^-]*\$//g'\`` it's supposed to remove the last field of a line with - separated fields, but it doesn't work if the last field is made of words separated by blanks. Why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38698/discussion-between-l19-and-ysth)

Answer (score 0):

No need to ever call sed from perl as the perl regex engine already built in and much easier to use.  The above answer is perfectly fine.  With such a simple dataset, another simple way to do it a little more idiomatically (although maybe a little more obfuscated...then again that sed command was a little complex in itself!) would be:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $id_play = 3;
my @result = map { s/;/-/g; $_ } grep { /^\w+;$id_play;/ } <DATA>;
print @result;

__DATA__
C00010018;1;17/10/2013;17:00;18;920;113;NONE
C00010019;1;18/10/2013;17:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010020;1;19/10/2013;19:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010020;3;19/10/2013;19:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010019;3;18/10/2013;17:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010020;4;19/10/2013;19:00;3;920;0;NONE
```

Assuming the file isn't too terribly large, you can just use grep with a regex to grab the lines you are looking for, and then map with a substitution operator to covert those semicolons to hyphens and store the results in a list that you can then print out.  I tested it with the **DATA** block below the code, but instead of reading in from that block, you would probably read in from your file as normal.

**edit**: Also forgot to mention that in sed, '(' and ')' are treated as literal regular characters and not regex groupings.  If you're dead set on sed for such things, use the -r option of sed to have it use those characters in the regex sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat file
C00010018;1;17/10/2013;17:00;18;920;113;NONE
C00010019;2;18/10/2013;17:00;18;920;0;NONE
C00010020;3;19/10/2013;19:00;18;920;0;NONE
$ 
$ id_play=2                                                  
$ 
$ awk -v id="$id_play" -F';' -v OFS='-' '$2==id{$1=$1}1' file
C00010018;1;17/10/2013;17:00;18;920;113;NONE
C00010019-2-18/10/2013-17:00-18-920-0-NONE
C00010020;3;19/10/2013;19:00;18;920;0;NONE
```