# Case-insensitive search with sed

Tags: shell, unix, sed

I have a file like this:

```
This     is    my work
This is my work
This is     my    WORK
```

I want to search all patterns irrespective of spaces and upper/lower cases. How can I do this using sed?

Comment: "search all patterns" - What patterns do you have? Maybe an example would help.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need `sed` for this. `grep` with ignore case and the quantifier `*` on each space is more than sufficient.

```
grep -i 'This *is *my *work' Input.txt
```

If you insist on sed, you can use this crazy hack from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665662/391161), as shown below.

```
sed  's/This *is *my *work/&/I;tx;d;:x' Input.txt
```

You can also use the following variation of jkyako's answer.

```
sed -n '/This *is *my *work/Ip' Input.txt
```

Note that if you do not want to match lines that simply **contain** the pattern, but only lines that *match* the pattern, you will have to anchor your pattern with `^` and `$`.

```
sed -n '/^This *is *my *work/Ip$' Input1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I didn't allow for spaces in my original answer.
This should solve that problem.

```
grep -i "this\s*is\s*my\s*work" file
```

Comment: ...which is why I'd recommend using grep and not sed for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Specifically using sed you could try the following, perhaps there's a shorter way:

```
sed -n '/[Tt][Hh][Ii][Ss] *[Ii][Ss] *[Mm][Yy] *[Ww][Oo][Rr][Kk]/p'
```