# Turn IANA backward file to a json file with bash script

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed

## What

I'd like to turn the [iana backward timezones file](http://web.mit.edu/freebsd/head/contrib/tzdata/backward) into a json file with unique keys, but in order to do that I'll have to make sure that the **keys become the values** and **vice versa**.

That's because a json file can't have duplicate keys.

## Example:

That file contains lot's of duplicate links, but for this example let's use these two:

```
Link    America/Toronto     America/Montreal
Link    America/Toronto     Canada/Eastern
```

I want those to turn into:

"America/Montreal": "America/Toronto",
"Canada/Eastern": "America/Toronto",

so that they both output Toronto.

## What I've tried so far:

The regular expression I've made so far is [this](https://regex101.com/r/SOeV8j/3):

- search for: `^Link[\s]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)[\s]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)$`
- replace with: `"\2" : "\1",`

Finally I tried doing this with sed like so:
`sed -E 's|^Link[\s]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)[\s]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward`

but for some reason it keeps outputting the whole file without substituting anything.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think that your command is almost correct. So for the regex, how about modifying from ``[\s]`` to ``\s``? It's ``sed -E 's|^Link\s*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)\s*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward``. If this was not what you want, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suggest using `jq`, a tool built with JSON in mind (which thus -- unlike `sed` -- is incapable of generating output which *is not* valid JSON, unless explicitly directed to).

The below is written to favor readability over terseness:

```
input='
Link    America/Toronto     America/Montreal
Link    America/Toronto     Canada/Eastern
'

# -R == raw input; -n == don't consume input until directed by "input" or "inputs"
jq -Rn '
# start by creating an array of smaller arrays, one per line
[inputs
 | select((. | length) > 1)    ## ignore empty lines
 | split("[[:space:]]+"; "")   ## Split on runs of whitespace
 | select(.[0] == "Link")]     ## Ignore anywhere first column is not "Link"
# then combine those smaller arrays to create key/value pairs in one big object
| reduce .[] as $item ({}; .[$item[2]]=$item[1])
' <<<"$input"
```

...properly emits:

```
{
  "America/Montreal": "America/Toronto",
  "Canada/Eastern": "America/Toronto"
}
```

...as  you can see at https://jqplay.org/s/RBBKMUS2pv

---

Alternately, that same logic written in Python (wrapped for invocation from shell):

```
# capture your Python code in a variable via a quoted heredoc
# this lets it be included in your shell script as a literal
link2json_py=$(cat <<'EOF'
import json, sys

data = {}
for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.rstrip()
    columns = line.split()
    if len(columns) < 3:
        continue
    if columns[0] != 'Link':
        continue
    data[columns[1]] = columns[2]
json.dump(data, sys.stdout)
sys.stdout.write('\n')
EOF
)

# define a shell function wrapping that Python code
link2json() {
  python -c "$link2json_py" "$@"
}

# and call that shell function
link2json <<<"$input"
```

Comment: What a great answer. This looks promising, but I want to be able to use the same command in multiple work stations without installing any 3rd party tools

Comment: I'd consider Python, then -- available everywhere, with a JSON generation library built in.

Comment: Using Python is more portable than relying on proprietary (vendor-specific) extensions to `sed`, at least. :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using GNU sed. Your problem comes from specificities of GNU extended regular expressions that are, unfortunately, not very well documented. From [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html), for instance:

> The shorthand
>   classes `\w`, `\W`, `\s` and `\S` can be used instead of `[[:alnum:]_]`,
>   `[^[:alnum:]_]`, `[[:space:]]` and `[^[:space:]]`. You can use these
>   directly in the regex, but not inside bracket expressions. A backslash
>   inside a bracket expression is always a literal.

So, you cannot use the `\s` shorthand for `[:space:]` inside a `[...]` set definition. As noted by [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike) you do not need set definitions and:

```
sed -E 's|^Link\s*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)\s*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward
```

should work. If, for any reason, you want to use set definitions,

```
sed -E 's|^Link[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)[[:space:]]*([a-zA-Z\/\-]*)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward
```

should also work. Note that:

```
 sed -E 's|^Link\s+([a-zA-Z\/\-]+)\s+([a-zA-Z\/\-]+)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward
```

is probably better. And:

```
 sed -E 's|^Link\s+([[:alpha:]/-]*)\s+([[:alpha:]/-]*)$|"\2" : "\1"|' ./backward
```

even better.

Comment: Solution 1, 3 and 4 does not work. Solution 2 is the only one that works! I just tried all of the above commands on OSX

Comment: The OP is on MacOS, so GNU sed seems unlikely (unless they explicitly installed it).

Comment: @SudoPlz: Glad to read that at least one solution worked. If you want to use the GNU utilities instead of the default ones you can install them with [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) or [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/). I am currently on macOS High Sierra and I use the GNU sed port by MacPorts. All solutions I show have been tested under this environment.

Comment: Got it, thank you so much @RenaudPacalet, but for now I think I'll use the 2nd just so that I don't have to install anything externally.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution:

The answer to my question the solution is the following command:

`sed -En 's|^Link[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)$|    "\2" : "\1"|p' ./backward`

It works as expected and creates the body of the JSON output

### TL/DR:

Specifically Renaud's answer made me realise that I have to use `[[:space:]]` instead of `[/s]`.

After running his command I was left with a couple of unwanted lines:

**A)** comments that the file contains on top

i.e `# This file is...`

(That was resolved by telling `sed` to not print lines that don't match (found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1665574/1658268)) by adding the `-n` flag in the beginning and the `p` flag in the end of the script)
and

**B)** some lines that were not converted

i.e `Link   Pacific/Pago_Pago   Pacific/Samoa`

(That was resolved by telling `sed` to match anything that is not a space in the group `[^[:space:]]`)

### Finally the whole script:

looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "{";
sed -En 's|^Link[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]*)$|    "\2": "\1"|p' ./backward
echo "}";
```

And running the script like so: `sh index.sh > timezones.json` outputs a beautiful json file.